# How to make an iterator that filters lists?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I have a generator function that filters a list:

```
def gen_func(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        if "?" in number:
            yield number

for item in gen_func(["trunk", "tr?ee", "+lea?f"]):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
tr?ee
lea?f
```

I tried writing an iterator expecting to get the same output but I get a None returned as the first item:

```
class GenClass:

    def __init__(self, numbers):
        self.current = 0
        self.numbers = numbers

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        next_value = self.current   

        if next_value >= len(self.numbers):
            raise StopIteration
        output = self.numbers[self.current]
        self.current += 1

        if "?" in output:
            return output

genclass = GenClass(["trunk", "tr?ee", "+lea?f"])
for num in genclass:
    print(num)
```

Output:

```
None
tr?ee
lea?f
```

How can I get just `tr?ee` and `lea?f` instead of the above?
Also, does this iterator make sense or am I misusing iterators here?

Comment: `if "?" in output:` and if not... you return `None`

Comment: My guess is that __next__ still returns, you might need to call self.__iter__ to jump to the next location. Something like that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I get that. How not to return None? `continue` won't work here.

Comment: `while True: if something: return foo`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code of `__next__` to:

```
        next_value = self.current

        if next_value >= len(self.numbers):
            raise StopIteration

        output = self.numbers[self.current]
        while "?" not in output:
            self.current += 1
            output = self.numbers[self.current]

        self.current += 1
        return output
```

This returns:

```
tr?ee
+lea?f
```

Essentially you loop over numbers and only return if number contains `?`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *yield* instead of *return* and imlement __iter__ only.

```
class GenClass:
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        self.numbers = numbers

    def __iter__(self):
        for value  in self.numbers:
            if '?' in value:
                yield value


genclass = GenClass(["trunk", "tr?ee", "+lea?f"])
for num in genclass:
    print(num)

Out:
tr?ee
+lea?f
```

My solution above isn't *iterator* but *iterable*, thanks [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga).  I think it's better to separate *iterable* and *iterator*, in such case you can implement GenClass and *iterator* separately. So if you will iterate through GenClass instance once, you can repeat it without counter resetting (GenClassIterator from [Daniel Mesejo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4001592/daniel-mesejo)'s solution).

```
class GenClass:
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        self.numbers = numbers

    def __iter__(self):
        return GenClassIterator(self.numbers)


class GenClassIterator:
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        self.numbers = numbers
        self.current = 0

    def __next__(self):
        next_value = self.current

        if next_value >= len(self.numbers):
            raise StopIteration

        output = self.numbers[self.current]
        while "?" not in output:
            self.current += 1
            output = self.numbers[self.current]

        self.current += 1
        return output

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Comment: You *could* do this, but then, you defined an *iterable* not an iterator. That may be ok. But the OP already has this solution.

Comment: You're right. So if _iterator_ is required, i think, it will be better to separate _iterable_ object and _iterator_ itself. In that case _iterable_ may be re-used without counter resetting

Answer (score 0):

Keep popping items from `numbers` till one one meets the criteria then return it.

```
import collections
class GenClass:

    def __init__(self, numbers):
        self.numbers = collections.deque(numbers)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                next_value = self.numbers.popleft()
            except IndexError as e:
                raise StopIteration

            if "?" in next_value:
                return next_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call next(self) to return desired value without returning None

```
class GenClass:

def __init__(self, numbers):
    self.current = 0
    self.numbers = numbers

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    next_value = self.current   

    if next_value >= len(self.numbers):
        raise StopIteration
    output = self.numbers[self.current]
    self.current += 1

    if "?" in output:
        return output
    else:
        return next(self)  # Skip value


genclass = GenClass(["trunk", "tr?ee", "+lea?f"])
for num in genclass:
     print(num)
```

Here's an updated version that doesn't store all the values during iteration

```
class GenClass:

def __init__(self, numbers):
    self.numbers = iter(numbers)

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    output = next(self.numbers)
    if "?" in output:
        return output
    else:
        return next(self)
```